# Email notification for follow-up comments can be confusing if my own comment is "buried"

Tags: feature-request, email, email-notification

When I click on an email notification due to a follow-up to my own comment, if my comment (as well as the new one) is a late one and buried under "show 5 more comments" then it can be hard to figure out why I was sent to that page.  Scanning around or text-searching for my name doesn't get me there.

I have two suggestions.

One is that the notification should say clearly that "there was a follow-up comment to an answer that you commented on"

The other is that the notification link should bring up the page with that particular answer's comments already expanded.